# Find significant neighborhoods with increase or decrease in #CurrentVisits compared to #BeforeVisits

Tags: regression, spss, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression

I am currently researching on some patients data to understand the effect of a hospital's inauguration over the current visits of the patients compared to their Before visits. The study area contains 57 neighborhoods. Also, I have calculated #Before visits and #Currentvisits of each patient. 
So, for each data row, I have patient demographics, #Visits Count, TimeCode (identifying Before or Current Visits) and Neighborhood of the patient.
So, I have the term TimeCode(Before/Current) and Neighborhood as my independent variables and #Visits as my dependent variable.
I am trying to use poisson regression and SPSS to perform this analysis.

And I geocoded these patients and used ArcMAP for validations purposes.
What is the best strategy to achieve this requirement?

Update1: Sample data

[image]

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: @user2974951, I have edited my question with some sample data.

Comment: So you have a number of (unique) patients, each from a neighborhood. You want to test which neighborhood has higher difference between current and before visits? Have you tried a regular linear model, I don't think this is count data anymore.